# popup с img и button

Tags: html, css

есть структура:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <button type="button" class="popup__close-button"></button>
    <img src="./images/art7.jpg" alt="фото превью" class="popup__big-picture">
  </div>
</div>
```

popup__container - флекс, центрирующий содержимое
у popup__big-picture ширина высчитывается width: calc(98% - 32px); (32 остается под popup__close-button)
Проблема: если я делаю экран меньше по вертикали, то img "вылетает" за пределы экрана.
Вопрос: есть ли способ css добиться отображения img без вылетов как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали?
Примечение: размеров img заранее не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от того, каким вы хотите видеть изображение. Как вариант, я так делаю, если не знаю пропорции изображения:

```
.popup__container{
    width: 50vw;/* или 50% от ширины экрана, можно также и привязывать к высоте */
}
.popup__big-picture{
    width: calc(50vw - 32px);
    height: calc(50vw - 32px); /* делаем квадрат */
    object-fit: cover; /* растягиваем изображение пропорционально */
}
```